# Determine the Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Determine the Laurent Series Expansion for the function

$$(z^2-1)\exp\left(\frac{2z}{z-1}\right)$$

at $a=1$ and find its ring of convergence.

I expanded the exponential function but I couldn't get it to work out properly. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help you in the future http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{2z}{z-1}=2+\frac2{z-1}.$$
Plus, you know something about $\exp(u+v)$, right?

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, should've spotted that!